# How is 'specific' data found and taken from a Semiconductor Memory Source?

Tags: digital-logic, memory, computer-architecture, ram

In a semiconductor memory chip, each bit of binary data is stored in a tiny circuit called a memory cell consisting of one to several transistors. Volatile type.

*Suppose an application stored its data in a particular segment on the computers RAM.*

How would the CPU know what data to extract and how would it sort through the other data to get to it. If everything in its core level is 0 or 1 its hard to distinguish what purpose 'x' memory has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, a memory is controlled by several *address* inputs, as well as a read/write control signal and some inputs that control **when** the read or write operation should occur.

Given *n* address inputs, 2<sup>*n*</sup> locations in the memory can be distinguished. These are the "specific" locations that the computer is able to access. Usually each location contains more than one bit. It could be a byte (8 bits, or memory cells), or a multi-byte word, which could be 16, 32, or 64 bits *wide*.

If you have a megabyte of memory, with single-byte access, you will need 20 address bits (individual input signals) to control it. For a gigabyte of memory, you would need 30 address bits.

> How would the CPU know what data to extract and how would it sort through the other data to get to it?

Generally it's up to the programmer (if using assembly language) or the compiler (when using a higher-level language) to keep track of what data is stored at what address.

For example, if you write a C program with a global variable `x`, then the compiler will decide what location to store it at, and take care of generating instructions that access that location whenever your program needs to use `x`.

If you create a local variable `y` within a function, the compiler will actually keep track of that variable relative to the value held in a special *register* called the *stack pointer* (SP). Each time the function is called, SP might hold a different value. But `y` will be created anew with each call and stored at the same offset from SP (which is kept track of by the compiler and generally not seen by the programmer).

A third possibility is *heap* allocation. Meaning the storage space is allocated  from a "heap" of available memory. In some languages (Java, for example) the compiler might do most of the work of tracking heap memory. In C, the programmer is responsible for keeping track of heap memory. This is done with *pointer* variables, which basically encode the address where the program should access to get that particular data.

Answer (score 1):

The CPU (originally designed by humans) just follows the program instructions (written by humans) and goes to a particular **address** in its memory and fetches the binary data then does something with it (depending on the program instruction).

Unlike humans, computers have no problem with lots of  1's and 0's. They do not 'think' or 'know' anything (yet).

Comment: Q: How does it know what address to look in for the data?  A: It stores the address in a different memory location...  Q: How does it know that address?  A: it's stored in memory too  Q: ???   A: somewhere back at the beginning the actual wiring of the processor says what address to look in for the initial instructions.

Comment: @ChrisStratton  The address can come from a program instruction as in ' load this register with the contents of this address' , or it can be indexed as in ' move the data in this register to a base address plus the contents of the index register' etc. When the CPU first starts up it goes to a particular address where it expects to find its first instruction. This is 'hard wired' (pre-programmed logic) into the CPU design. How it interprets these instructions and the binary data (address, number,letter,index etc) that can follow it is also hard wired.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, it is exceedingly difficult because in general computers the memory locations have no meaning.  The series of bytes etc. at a location can be part of a picture, to an email address, to a recipe for taco's.  Every thing is in context.  SO the program has to remember where it put specific things and what format was used.  If anything is even the slightest bit off there is a good chance that it will fail to complete.

In fact in certain computers there is no real difference in storage between code and data.

There is only one thing for certain in a micro-processor and that is, on start up, the processor expects that at a reserved address that there will be a code word that is an instruction.  Everything else is built up on top of that.  That is why the process of starting up is called boot strapping - it literally means, grabbing on to your boot straps and lifting yourself off the ground.